# /usr/lib/libz.a not found when compiling Doom 3

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to compile the newly released Doom 3 source code, but got the error:

```
scons: *** [build/debug/core/sys/scons/doom] Source `/usr/lib/libz.a'
    not found, needed by target `build/debug/core/sys/scons/doom'.
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Does anyone know what I should do? (I am on Ubuntu 11.04)

Comment: where are yiou getting this source code from? and what system are you using?

Comment: Install [zlib](http://zlib.net/)...

Comment: @DanZimm https://github.com/TTimo/doom3.gpl

Comment: @Mankarse do you think I can get that with apt-get?

Comment: @Mark: Almost certainly.

Comment: @Mankarse what is the package called?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install `zlib1g-dev` or your distribution's equivalent `zlib` development package. You may need to fiddle with the `scons` library paths too, as the file is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a` on my system.

Comment: I am on 32 bit ubuntu 11.04 linux system, and zlib1g-dev is install according to apt-get...

Comment: What does `dpkg -L zlib1g-dev | grep libz.a` look like?

Comment: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.a I guess I should edit the scons path then. Have you installed doom 3? Do you know which part I should modify?

Comment: I haven't installed it, but just skimming through the scons configuration, it looks like you might need to modify `CORELIBPATH` or `BASELINKFLAGS`. Another option is to symlink the `libz.a` to `/usr/lib/libz.a` and see if that's good enough to skip this. :)

Comment: I found in / neo / sys / scons / SConscript.curl has the line curl_libs = [ target_name, '/usr/lib/libz.a' ] do you think that is it?

Comment: It could be -- but I wouldn't be surprised if other portions of Doom3 used zlib too -- so you may need to modify more paths.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on the 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you will need to use the `lib32z1-dev` package, and symlink the file provided by that package.  Linking the 64-bit version will not work (for obvious reasons).

Adding this answer despite an earlier accepted answer because I found this question from Google and other 64-bit users might also find it from Google.